# GUI alternative to <select> when you have a lot of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

**A `<select>` might be good for choosing between 3-15 simple items, but how do you deal with 15-100+?**

**The simplest option** would be to just have a plain `<select>` with a lot of `<option>`s, but it's not very user friendly. There's a lot of scrolling and it might be hard to find the option you are looking for. The benefit is that you can (maybe with scrolling) see all the options you have.

**A more advanced option** would be to have a text field with autocomplete. A user types in a letter or two, and search results come back which you choose from. It makes it easier to find the option you are looking for - if you know what you *are* looking for. The drawback is that the user can't see all the options.

**An even more advanced option** would be to build a "search, list and choose" widget which defaults to show X items, but allows you to search. An advantage of this approach is that I can allow search on multiple attributes and not just the name of the item which is to be selected.

1. **What solutions have you deployed in
   these situations?**
2. **Is there a jQuery plugin I should know about?**

Comment: Dojo has a FilteringSelect widget, so there must be something for jQuery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The solution that I like to use is provide the user a select list with all the options (should they want to look through it), but provide an autocomplete feature which searches through the list as they type into it. Sort of a hybrid of your first and second options.
2. As for plug-ins, there are a number out there (as well as documentation which will lead you to more) that can help you here:

   - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-select-autocomplete
   - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete
   - http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at Choosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen
That's a jQuery plugin that generate a nicer select with a text field to search into.
This solution let the user see all options and search for one in particular without having to scroll.

Comment: As of 2023, Chosen is deprecated, development is stalled (but it may work well).

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Unobtrusive Fast-filter Dropdown (UFD)](http://code.google.com/p/ufd/) jquery plugin. This is by far my favorite and performs very well across different browsers even ie6. It can easily be styled and is definitely fast. It can managed thousands of items and is faster than jQuery UI's combobox autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) for jQuery and there is [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) in jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has an [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) control.  You can tie this together with a callback function as the data source and use Ajax to pull in large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution that I've seen a few good textual implementations of is a [fish eye selector](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/fisheyemenu/) used on vertical lists. There are lots of [javascript/CSS](http://javascript.internet.com/css/fisheye.html), Flash and Java examples online.

Answer (score 1):

If the options naturally form groups, you could consider using [HTML optgroups](http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_optgroup_tag.cfm) instead of a javascript-based solution. It makes a large set of options much more organized and manageable, while still keeping all options visible.

I don't know what server-side language/framework you're using to generate your HTML, but for example in Ruby on Rails you can use grouped_options_for_select to generate optgroups automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I like autocomplete selects when there are many options to choose from.  I found a jQuery example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following as suggested in above answers:
    plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-select-autocomplete
    docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete
    jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/
    Unobtrusive Fast-filter Dropdown (UFD)

I found UFD to be the one I liked best as it behaved most like a drop down and had a lot of versatility built into it, also the others were a bit buggy.

BUT it still didn't give me consistency across browsers.  I want it to work the same way in all browsers.  For example:
  In a normal select element, if I type the first letter, it will take me to the first option beginning with that letter and if I then hit Enter, it will select it, BUT here is where it differs from browser to browser.  Some browsers fire the onchange event when Enter is hit and some don't until the dropdown loses focus.

UFD didn't have the "onchange" consistency I was looking for

Comment: It will help you to create a new question for your own question! No one will answer an answer ;)