# HTML select-option in reverse direction?

Tags: html, popup

I have a small problem with an HTML select:

```
<select>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

By default all the options will be shown underneath the select field and I can't seem to change their direction. What I need is to show up over the select field instead of underneath. 
How would that be possible?

Comment: It's not possible without using a full-blown JavaScript alternative to the select tag

Comment: Does that javascript alternative come as a plugin of some kind?

Comment: Move it close to the bottom of the screen :).

Comment: @Severin there are plenty... eg [GUI alternative to <select> when you have a lot of options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5266250) but starting to use one of them just to achieve this is likely overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much impossible (without custom JavaScript-based elements) since `select` and `option` are elements built-in to the OS and browser.

One way to think about it: all drop-down menus are styled so that all listings are below the field. If you make yours different, some people may be confused, and that's not a good thing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply - I have to find a different solution then I guess.

Comment: @Severin try creating a "fake" select, using divs, ul/ol, etc...i had to do this here because of incompatibility on browsers and OS's

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible dude, sory... I have done the research for you but nothing appears to be a solution to your problem...

Seeing it the good way, you might be the one that comes up with the JavaScript code for this and post the solution on your own question, and answer the question for future users that need the same stuff

Keep moving and you'll get it. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use this in your CSS:

```
direction: rtl;
```

You can do it inline for your select or give it a class/id. I was able to reverse the direction of my select menu by using this. I had to change some of the styles though because it pushed my text to the right a bunch. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275891/how-to-reverse-the-direction-in-html5-range-input).

Hope that helps!